# MySQL to find gaps in time based records for a given timeframe

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a large (> 250M rows * 92 columns) table that records data from 20 vehicles on average 4 times a second. One thing I would like to do with this data is to find times where the gap between records is more than 1 second over a given time period and record the vehicle position.

ie, for vehicle id (VehId) 203 how many >1 second gaps between 2022-04-15 and 2022-04-16 and record the time (RealTime) and where the gap occured

| Row | Id | VehId | RealTime | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 741629223 | 203 | 2022-04-15 18:00:00 | 1206816 |
| 2 | 741629224 | 203 | 2022-04-15 18:00:00 | 1206816 |
| 3 | 741629225 | 203 | 2022-04-15 18:00:00 | 1206817 |
| 4 | 741629226 | 203 | 2022-04-15 18:00:00 | 1206819 |
| 5 | 741629230 | 203 | 2022-04-15 18:00:04 | 1206980 |
| 6 | 741629222 | 203 | 2022-04-15 18:00:04 | 1206980 |

As can be seen from above, there is a 4 second gap between rows 4 and 5. I would like an output like:

| Row | Id | VehId | RealTime_Start | Position_Start | RealTime_End | Position_End | Timeout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 741629226 | 203 | 2022-04-15 18:00:00 | 1206819 | 2022-04-15 18:00:04 | 1206980 | 4 |

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A query on a table with 250 million rows needs to be tuned appropriately. The first approximation of a query can take the form:

```
select
  row, id, vehid, realtime, position as position_start, nextpos as positionend
from (
  select t.*,
    case when date_sub(lead(realtime) over(partition by vehid order by realtime),
      interval 4 second) > realtime) then 1 else 0 end as gap
    lead(position) over(partition by vehid order by realtime) as nextpos
  from t
  where vehid = 203 and realtime between '2022-04-15' and '2022-04-16'
) x
where gap = 1
```

I would make sure one of the following indexes is created in the database, to avoid a table scan:

```
create index ix1 on t (vehid, realtime);

create index ix2 on t (vehid, realtime, position);
```

You'll need to get the execution plan and verify it's using the indexes. If it isn't there are some tricks to encourage the engine to do it.

Comment: Thank you.I have set the indexing going, might take a while